# Is it possible to only allow a person to open a chest if he has an item in his inventory in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In other words: If a person has, say, a gold ingot named "Bob" in his inventory, the chest will open and he may view its contents. If such an ingot is absent, he will be unable to view the contents of the chest.

What I'm trying to do is develop a safety deposit box system, where if a player has a "key" he may open the box, but otherwise the chest stays locked. I'm trying to avoid [complicated redstone contraptions](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/334535-working-safety-deposit-box-system) while trying to stay in vanilla MC. If my "key" idea doesn't work, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lock a chest but it will require a command.

This will set a locked chest:

```
 /setblock x y z minecraft:chest 0 0 {Lock:Key}
```

x y z being coordinates.  In this case you would have to have an item named 'Key' in your hand to open the chest.  (otherwise it says chest is locked)

One thing to note, if you break the chest, it will drop it's contents onto the ground.

Also, just in case you haven't discovered it.  An ender chest will keep your items safe from others.  If you combine that with shulker boxes, you can store quite a lot of items.

---

Edit:

Other items besides chests can be locked.  I used another command to test them:

```
/blockdata ~ ~-1 ~ {Lock:Key}
```

I set several items that contain an inventory.  I jumped on top of each and used the above command.

All items in image successfully locked
[image: LockedItems]

Comment: Cool. Never knew such a data tag existed. Let me check this out tomorrow, and if it works I'll award you your check mark. Thanks! Destroying the chest won't be an issue if you're on adventure mode. The way I have the map set up, ender chests just won't quite do what I had in mind, but that's also a good thought. Just out of curiosity, does the {Lock} tag apply to all blocks with GUI's? All blocks that can contain items? Or just chests?

Comment: I had never tried.  I tested them and edited answer to include results.

Comment: All blocks that can hold items. Interesting. So you can't lock, for instance, crafting tables? I'll have to check that one out.

Comment: I only tried the items in the image and shulker boxes(which won't lock).  Let me know if you find any other items.

Comment: Negative on crafting tables and anvils. Error "the target block is not a data holder block." Same goes for any block that doesn't have a GUI (deduction from the few I tested). The jukebox, ender chest, bed, and enchanting table took the lock tag, but they didn't actually lock. Not sure why you weren't able to lock shulker boxes; using the `/blockdata ~ ~-1 ~ {Lock:Key}` code you provided I was able to lock them successfully.

Comment: Interesting I just checked again and was able to lock a shulker box. Perhaps I was part way off the box the first time and tried to lock some air and so it gave me same error you got for craft table.

Comment: Shulker boxes are interesting in that when they are broken, they drop the usual shulker box with any contained items.  When placed again, they are still locked.  The shulker itself could be destroyed to destroy contents but no one without key could ever access the contents.  A mobile safety deposit box of sorts.